# LibVNC Compile Error on Windows: Unresolved External Symbol

Tags: c, vnc, appveyor, vnc-viewer, tightvnc

In need of a bit of help here: I've spent all day trying to compile `libvncserver` (https://github.com/LibVNC/libvncserver) on a Windows 10 computer. I'm following the commands listed here (https://github.com/LibVNC/libvncserver/blob/master/.appveyor.yml#L48) and running them line by line in my terminal. The issue I'm having is on line 47 (the `nmake` command), I get the following error in my console:

[image]

Has anyone had success compiling this library on Windows, and if so, could you provide some guidance? Am I compiling it correctly by following the appveyor file? Thank you!!

Comment: Please do not post text as images - [reasoning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Please post it as text in the question.

Answer (score 0):

/f should be -f after nmake command
Also you should use the specified include path with double quotes("")